# How to index words and put their page number on last page?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, indexing

I have highlighted a number of words in my document using `\textbf{}` that I would like to collect in a table-of contents (or index) style table with the words on one side and the pages they were highlighted on, on the left side, in the end of the rendered document. Is this even possible or is this too complicated?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is going to reply to your question but you can use the package `\usepackage{imakeidx}` and `\makeindex` before your doc.
For every word you wish to include, you would have to use the command `\index{}`after and finally `\printindex` at the end of your doc

So, in practice

```
     \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{imakeidx} %package
    \makeindex %compulsory command
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \section{Explaining stratigraphy}
    In this section, I will explain the concepts of stratigraphy \index{stratigraphy}, strata \index{strata} and deposit \index{deposit}. 
    
    \newpage
    
    \section{Definitions}
    In this section, I will define the following words: latex \index{latex}, index \index{index} ...

\newpage

This is a new page for the example \index{example}

    
    \printindex %to print
    \end{document}
```

Will give you:
[image]

Comment: Looking how to customize this, I found an overleaf tutorial : https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/indices which has a similar code but also explain how to change the format